# PHP strtotime() function that accepts a format?

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime, mktime

`strtotime()` in PHP works great if you can provide it with a date format it understands and can convert, but for example you give it a UK date it fails to give the correct unix timestamp.

Is there any PHP function, official or unofficial, that can accept a format variable that tells the function in which format the date and time is being passed?

The closest I have come to doing this is a mixture of `date_parse_from_format()` and `mktime()`

```
// Example usage of the function I'm after
//Like the date() function but in reverse
$timestamp = strtotimeformat("03/05/2011 16:33:00", "d/m/Y H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.3:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', '03/05/2011 16:33:00');
echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: Im looking to return a unix timestamp not the date in another string format.

Comment: @Andrew - meze changed his answer it didn't originally have getTimestamp();

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [strptime](http://php.net/strptime), I think. you can use it to parse the date and then use [mktime](http://php.net/mktime) if you need a UNIX timestamp.

```
function strotimeformat($date, $format) {
  $d = strptime($date, $format);
  return mktime($d['tm_hour'], $d['tm_min'], $d['tm_sec'],
                $d['tm_mon'], $d['tm_mday'], $d['tm_year']);
}
```

This will work with PHP 5.1 and onwards.

Comment: no I'm not, I'm looking for something that returns a unix timestamp to an array of values. Plus strptime is not implemented on Windows so not an ideal solution.

Comment: Ok. I've updated my answer with a function to give you a timestamp anyway (still not working on Windows though). You can of course do some substring+strpos work (or explode+rearrange+implode) to make it into a US date.

Comment: As mentioned in my question Im already using a combination of `date_parse_from_format()` and `mktime()` in the same way you have shown your code. `date_parse_from_format()` works for all systems but only works on PHP 5.3 >= wereas strptime works on an earlier version but not windows. I'll leave the question open for a few days to see if any other answers come in.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to have a format argument? Maybe you can just throw out date_parse_from_format() and use sscanf() instead? That would give you support on most platforms.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` assumes it's a US date/time when using `/` as the separator.  To get it to think it's a Euro date/time, use `-` or `.` as the date separator.  You can change the `/`s to `-`s or `.`s with a simple `str_replace()`

Comment: Read the question... I'm quite aware of what strtotime is capable of and how to work around. But that's not what I'm asking... I'm asking for a function that accepts a date in any format along with a string that says what format that date is in and return a unix timestamp.