# How to display time in PHP by date() function

Tags: php

I get the value `9.0` from a CSV file that I would like to print as the time `09:00:00`
If i try

```
<?php
$time = 9.01;
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($time));
```

It displays `09:01:00`.
But if I try

```
<?php
$time = 9;
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($time)); or echo date('H:i:s', strtotime(9.00));
```

It displays 01:00:00.
I want to get time 09:00:00.

Comment: Your problem is you are using a non standard format in _strtotime_ (that is supposed to take a string as parameter, not a double).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP strtotime() function that accepts a format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871963/php-strtotime-function-that-accepts-a-format)

Comment: How are you reading the CSV? It sounds like somewhere along the line your data is being converted to an integer or float, which strtotime won't always be able to deal with. The string `'9.00'` should work fine.

Comment: As I saved xls to csv data automatically converted to float and integer according to value like 09.01 converted to 9.01 and 09.00 converted to 9

Comment: Is this the problem in my CSV file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
$time =  9;
echo date( 'H:i:s', strtotime( number_format($time, 2)));
```

Comment: I need to import csv file to update database and in csv file if time 9.00 it automatically converted to 9 and strtotime('9') give me 01:00:00

Comment: @Deepak3301086 I think this solution is more correct, just convert to string

Comment: @Deepak3301086 try something like  this

Comment: You can use [`number_format($number, 2)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to force two digits after the decimal point.

Comment: If i convert to string then also strtotime('9') not work

Comment: @Philipp Maurer, Thanks number_formate($number, 2) work for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to fill a date variable with any value you need:

```
<?php
$d=mktime(9, 0, 0);
echo "Created date is " . date("h:i:s", $d);
?>
```

See the documentation of [mktime](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

Comment: I tryed  $t = '9';        $d = mktime($t); because my time come from csv, and it is also not work for me

Comment: You need to fill all the values $d=mktime(hours, min, sec); or you can try this $d=mktime($t, 0, 0);

Comment: Do you means that, First i need to check value if float then explode and put in mktime($t[0], $t[1], 0) and if integer then put value same like mktime($t, 0, 0)?

Comment: @Himas Not all the parameters are required, the documentation explains that they are optional. It's only forbidden to call it without *any* argument, we should use `time` instead.

Comment: @AnthonyB yes true, but to be compatible with the date format we need to fill them. so that he can display {9:00:00} as desired.

Comment: @Himas I agree. It's up to the OP to check its date format and then to fill the arguments in mktime function. I think the example is now clear enough.

Comment: @AnthonyB the last edit is good, but idk it's clear now, do u think it is better to approve it?

Comment: @Himas According to me (but I may be wrong), my last edit shows the time as it is from its CSV file, and how to get it working with `mktime`. I think it's relevant with the question. But it is your answer, it's up to you to accept or refuse my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the main issue is the import CSV has a malformed date. Assuming you cannot change it and that the value is `{hours}.{minutes}`. Minutes not being a fraction but a value between 0 - 60. Otherwise, this will need adjusting to convert the fraction of an hour into minutes.

I'm using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class to achieve this.

```
$value = 9.1;

if (is_float($value)) {
    $hour = (int)$value;
    $minute = number_format(($value - floor($value)) * 100);

    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTime($hour, $minute);
} else {
    $date = new DateTime($value);
}

$formattedTime = $date->format('H:i');

echo $formattedTime . "\n";
```

Answer (score -2):

For **12 hours** Formate
echo date("h:i:s a");
For **24 hours** Formate
echo date("H:i:s");

Comment: This does not answer the question in any way.